# Flutter use TransformationController with statelessWidget and provider

Tags: flutter

i have interctiveViewer widget and i want to work with TransformationController to manage the zoom and trandform the scale, but i want to do it with state manager Provider and statelessWidget, because all example on the internet are using statefullWidget, please is there any example to do it with provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TransformationController` is a ValueNotifier(ChangeNotifier) so you can consume it with a `ValueListenableBuilder`, `AnimatedBuilder` or just Consumer which is part of Provider

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      // Provider the transformation controller
      value: TransformationController(),
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (BuildContext context, TransformationController value, _) {
          return InteractiveViewer(
            transformationController: value,
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue]),
              ),
              width: 2000,
              height: 2000,
              child: Center(
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    value.value = Matrix4.identity();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Raouf Rahiche thank you for your anser, but my build method is